# How to send python script results via Twilio

Tags: python-3.x, twilio

I have a short python 3 script that scrapes dynamic data from a website. I want Twilio to send the results of this script but don't know how to insert the scraped data into the body of the Twilio message. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: what are the results of the script? How are they formatted? Are you parsing the results or are they already cleaned to be sent?

Comment: Here is my code: ` import time
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get('https://XXXXXXX.com
    email = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_email')
    email.send_keys('XXXXXX')
    password = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
    password.send_keys('XXXXX')
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    total = browser.find_element_by_id('summaryOPS')
    print(total.text)`

Comment: do you just want to send `total.text`?

Comment: Yes, just send total.text

Comment: Is it a string or JSON? How long is it? Does `client.messages \
                .create(
                     body=total.text,
                     from_=your-twilio-number,
                     to=number-to-text
                 )` send `total.text`?

Comment: `my_phone_num = +1XXXXXXXXXX
account_sid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

#sms = client.messages.create(

client.messages \ .create(

            body=total.text
            from_="+14062154363",
            to=my_phone_num,
)

print(sms.sid)`

Comment: I tried that and I get an error `client.messages \ .create(
                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` I also have the `from twilio.rest import Client` at the top of the code

Comment: To answer your question from you last reply, `total.text' is a dollar amount. An example would be "$149.90'

Comment: I got it working! The only thing I changed was to replace `body="insert some text"` with `body=total.text` I think that is essentially what you had written before. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using

```
client.messages.create(body=total.text, from_=your-twilio-number, to=number-to-text)
```

should do the trick!